# Optimizing vector addition with ARM Neon intrinsics

Tags: xcode, assembly, arm, simd, neon

I tested using ARM Neon intrinsics for adding all components in a vector. I have non-NEON version of the same function, and a NEON-one. I did not get any performance improvement, it is about the same using intrinsics or not, sometimes even a bit slower. I was building for iPhone4S, compiled with -Os flag, LLVM/Clang, Xcode 5.0.2. My question is, how to use NEON instructions here in a way that would give a performance benefit.

Results from the test:

2014-04-18 20:51:45.587 ARMAssembly[9007:907] 1 performed in 185191

2014-04-18 20:51:45.596 ARMAssembly[9007:907] 2 performed in 180158

Here's the code i used.

```
int doStuffSIMD(int* arr, int size)
{
    uint32x4_t vec128 = vdupq_n_u32(0);
    for (int* i = &arr[0]; i < &arr[0] + size; i += 4)
    {
        uint32x4_t temp128 = vld1q_u32(i);
        vec128 = vaddq_u32 (vec128, temp128);
    }

    uint32x2_t a = vget_low_u32(vec128);
    uint32x2_t b = vget_high_u32(vec128);

    a = vadd_u32(a, b);
    uint32_t result;
    result = vget_lane_u32(a,0);
    result += vget_lane_u32(a,1);

    return result;
}

int doStuffNorm(int* arr, int size)
{
    int acc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 1)
    {
        acc += arr[i];
    }
    return acc;
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    const int size = 4096 * 4096;
    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    clock_t now;
    clock_t now2;

    now = clock();
    int i = doStuffSIMD(arr, size);
    now2 = clock();
    clock_t diff1 = now2 - now;

    now = clock();
    int j = doStuffNorm(arr, size);
    now2 = clock();
    clock_t diff2 = now2 - now;

    free(arr);
    NSLog(@"1 performed in %lu", (diff1));
    NSLog(@"2 performed in %lu", (diff2));

    NSLog(@"RESULT : %i / %i", i, j);


    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

The assembly for doStuffSIMD:

```
_doStuffSIMD:
    .cfi_startproc
Lfunc_begin0:
    .loc    1 17 0                  @ /Users/karikuvaja/Documents/ARMAssembly/ARMAssembly/main.m:17:0
@ BB#0:
    @DEBUG_VALUE: doStuffSIMD:arr <- R0+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: doStuffSIMD:size <- R1+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: i <- R0+0
    vmov.i32    q8, #0x0
Ltmp0:
    @DEBUG_VALUE: doStuffSIMD:vec128 <- Q8+0
    .loc    1 19 0 prologue_end     @ /Users/karikuvaja/Documents/ARMAssembly/ARMAssembly/main.m:19:0
    cmp r1, #1
    blt LBB0_3
@ BB#1:
Ltmp1:
    @DEBUG_VALUE: doStuffSIMD:arr <- R0+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: doStuffSIMD:size <- R1+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: i <- R0+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: doStuffSIMD:vec128 <- Q8+0
    add.w   r1, r0, r1, lsl #2
Ltmp2:
LBB0_2:                                 @ %.lr.ph
                                        @ =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    .loc    1 21 0                  @ /Users/karikuvaja/Documents/ARMAssembly/ARMAssembly/main.m:21:0
    vld1.32 {d18, d19}, [r0]!
    vadd.i32    q8, q8, q9
Ltmp3:
    @DEBUG_VALUE: doStuffSIMD:vec128 <- Q8+0
    .loc    1 19 0                  @ /Users/karikuvaja/Documents/ARMAssembly/ARMAssembly/main.m:19:0
    cmp r0, r1
    blo LBB0_2
Ltmp4:
LBB0_3:
    vadd.i32    d16, d16, d17
Ltmp5:
    @DEBUG_VALUE: __a <- D16+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: doStuffSIMD:a <- D16+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: __a <- D16+0
    .loc    1 31 0                  @ /Users/karikuvaja/Documents/ARMAssembly/ARMAssembly/main.m:31:0
    vmov.32 r0, d16[1]
Ltmp6:
    .loc    1 30 0                  @ /Users/karikuvaja/Documents/ARMAssembly/ARMAssembly/main.m:30:0
    vmov.32 r1, d16[0]
Ltmp7:
    @DEBUG_VALUE: doStuffSIMD:result <- R1+0
    .loc    1 31 0                  @ /Users/karikuvaja/Documents/ARMAssembly/ARMAssembly/main.m:31:0
    add r0, r1
Ltmp8:
    @DEBUG_VALUE: doStuffSIMD:result <- R0+0
    .loc    1 33 0                  @ /Users/karikuvaja/Documents/ARMAssembly/ARMAssembly/main.m:33:0
    bx  lr
Ltmp9:
Lfunc_end0:
```

**UPDATE:**

The NEON code now performs almost 3x faster than the normal version with iPhone4s, after a couple of changes, as suggested by BitBank in the comments : memory is prefetched and the loop is unrolled. I found prefetching 128 bytes to be the best fit for this particular device.

Results after optimisation:

2014-04-19 14:14:56.507 ARMAssembly[11492:907] 1 performed in 70096

2014-04-19 14:14:56.513 ARMAssembly[11492:907] 2 performed in 205114

The optimized loop looks like this:

```
int doStuffSIMD(unsigned int* arr, int size)
{


    uint32x4_t vec128 = vdupq_n_u32(0);
    uint32x4_t temp128 = vdupq_n_u32(0);
    for (unsigned int* i = &arr[0]; i < &arr[0] + size; i += 16)
    {

        __builtin_prefetch(i + 32);

        temp128 = vld1q_u32(i);
        vec128 = vaddq_u32 (vec128, temp128);

        temp128 = vld1q_u32(i + 4);
        vec128 = vaddq_u32 (vec128, temp128);

        temp128 = vld1q_u32(i + 8);
        vec128 = vaddq_u32 (vec128, temp128);

        temp128 = vld1q_u32(i + 12);
        vec128 = vaddq_u32 (vec128, temp128);
    }

    uint32x2_t a = vget_low_u32(vec128);
    uint32x2_t b = vget_high_u32(vec128);

    a = vadd_u32(a, b);
    uint32_t result;
    result = vget_lane_u32(a,0);
    result += vget_lane_u32(a,1);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You haven't provided exact figures or given us an idea of the value of 'size'. Since memory is so much slower than instruction execution, the NEON benefit is completely eclipsed by the memory load delay. Two suggestions: prefetch the data into the cache and unroll your loop to hide some of the loading delays, then you should see benefit to the NEON code.

Comment: size is mentioned in the main function,  `const int size = 4096 * 4096;`

Comment: @BitBank Added the test results in the description. Can you give an example how to prefetch the data in this case?

Comment: You need to use a PLD intrinsic (not sure the exact syntax, but it's probably __PLD(address). Point it to data a few hundred bytes ahead of what you're currently processing. You also need to unroll the loop. This is the idea you need to keep in your mind as you write the code - "If I'm not using all of the available registers, the code is slower than it could be".

Comment: PLD intrinsic was unavailable, but __builtin_prefetch seems to work.. now NEON-version is 2x faster than non-NEON version :)

Comment: You can use cache prefetch with the non-NEON version as well.

Comment: Yeah looking at the assembly, using __builtin_prefetch generated a PLD instruction.

Comment: Your loop unrolling is ineffective. You need to load multiple registers (which allows time for the values to actually get loaded), then add them. Doing load/add, load/add will produce the same stalls as in the original code.

Comment: @bitbank I did profile this and it did give performance improvement, over the non-unrolled one. I'm sure it can be improved though, can you be more specific how I can do this?

Comment: tmp1 = vld..., tmp2 = vld..., tmp3 = vld..., tmp4 = vld..., add tmp1..., add tmp2..., add tmp3... When you issue a load instruction, the actual load can take place hundreds of clock cycles later (they are queued). Issue a bunch of load instructions, then do the adds. That is what is meant by unrolling the loop.

Comment: @bitbank I tried unrolling the loop further, using 8 loads, first loading and then adding (also prefecthing was updated). For some reason it's now slower than it was before.. I also tried rearranging the current code (with 4 loads) so that loads are first and adds after, it didn't affect the performance

Comment: perhaps it's because compiler is reordering the adds (looking at the assembly it does).. might cause cache misses. It should not be any slower otherwise.

Comment: At this level of optimization, I usually write assembly language because compilers tend to mess things up.